# object is not an instance of it's class in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
class Custom extends Error {
constructor(message: string) {
super(message);
  }
}
const x = new Custom("");
console.log(x instanceof Custom); // false
console.log(x instanceof Error); // true
```

can someone help me by explaining why the object is not an instance of the class "Custom" in TypeScript?

i expect object "x" to be an instance of class "Custom"

Comment: [Works for me...](https://tsplay.dev/w2pnbm)

Comment: @vera. is right. It would seem you've oversimplified your example, and lost the actual problem in the process.

Comment: it works because tagret="es2017" in tsconfig file
it doesn't work in case of target="es5"

Comment: Yeah because ES5 doesn't have classes, and TypeScript does not do transpiling, so that is why you will get improper behaviors like this. If you must transpile to older versions, use a tool like Babel.